# Excel: Removing spaces in data

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I want to remove the space between BA and 1 but keep the space after 1.
Therefore I'm looking to have "BA1 0".

[image]

However, further downn my data. The postcodes become whole again e.g. BS15 1. And from these no spaces need to be removed. 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

SUBSTITUTE, which allows the specification of which one to replace:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1)
```

The `1` tells the formula to only substitute the 1st occurrence of the space.

Per your Edit add a check to see if the space needs to be removed:

```
=IF(MID(A1,3,1) = " ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1),A1)
```

Comment: Sorry question has been updated as I forgot to mention something

Comment: @wilga see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a formula-based answer and only need to do this once to tidy up a dataset, try using the Find/Replace tool. It's in the right-hand side of the Home ribbon.

1. Select the column
2. Open the Find/Replace tool
3. Find: "BA 1" (without the quote marks), or maybe Find "BA "
4. Replace: "BA1" (without the quote marks), or maybe Replace "BA"

It won't alter the rest of the cell so will leave the rest of the postcode correct.

You don't mention if your data has postcodes which only start with BA and BS, if your data has lots of variation in the first two characters, this probably isn't appropriate and you should try one of the other suggested solutions. But it works where you have a few big patterns.